# Unable to set Camera.rotation in three.js r73?

Tags: javascript, 3d, camera, three.js

i just use it after setting the camera position in the initialize.But not changes are visible . I also use Orbital controls in the same function.

```
Camera.rotation.x = 90*Math.PI/180;
```

Answer (score 0):

With OrbitControls you need to change these two vectors:

```
camera.position
controls.target
```

to change the camera position & lookAt.